# Scala: multiple pathPrefixes with Spray

Tags: scala, rest, api, routes, spray

I'm trying to create an API with Spray which listens to 2 prefixes. These 2 prefixes in turn listen to optional integers.

This is the setup that I am trying to achieve:

```
val itemRoute = {
  pathPrefix("configs") {
     <...>
  }

  pathPrefix("samples") {
    <...>   
  }
}
```

This way, the API can listen to calls like

```
http://www.example.com/samples/2
```

However, with said snippet, only one of the two prefixes are listened to.

I have tried different syntax styles, like putting a *~* inbetween twe pathPrefix blocks, and incorporating *pathPrefixTest*. Is this an issue with my syntax, and how can I achieve multiple pathPrefixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Akka http, Spray:

> spray is no longer maintained and has been superseded by Akka HTTP.
>   Please check out the migration guide for help with the upgrade.
>   Commercial support is available from Lightbend.

Anyway, that example would work:

```
package test

import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

import akka.http.scaladsl.Http

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object TesHttp {

   val routes = pathPrefix("configs") {
     complete {
       "configs" 
     }
   } ~ 
   pathPrefix("samples") { 
     complete {
       "samples"
      }
   }


  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val mat    = ActorMaterializer()
    import system.dispatcher

    println("Starting ..")
    val binding = Http().bindAndHandle(routes, interface = "localhost", 9091)
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issue. Especially the syntax for multiple pathPrefixes was unclear to me before.